# How to show the interface configuration under a interface?

Tags: cisco-router

How to show the interface configuration under a interface?

```
Router(config)#interface gigabitEthernet 2/1
Router(config-if)#
```

if i use Quidway switch or router when I under a interface, I can use `display this` to display self, but how to display this in Cisco IOS.